# Eclipse Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library

Tags: java, eclipse, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am almost new to java and I am trying to run a program in eclipse and the error I am getting is :"Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library"
I am using the latest java kit(jdk1.8.0_60) as well as the newest eclipse version all of them on win10.
here is the code I am trying to run :

```
package module1;

import processing.core.PApplet;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.UnfoldingMap;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.geo.Location;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.AbstractMapProvider;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.Google;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.MBTilesMapProvider;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.MapUtils;

/** HelloWorld
  * An application with two maps side-by-side zoomed in on different    locations.
  * Author: UC San Diego Coursera Intermediate Programming team
  * @author Your name here
  * Date: July 17, 2015
  * */

public class HelloWorld extends PApplet
{

    /** Your goal: add code to display second map, zoom in, and customize the backg`round.
     * Feel free to copy and use this code, adding to it, modifying it, etc.  
     * Don't forget the import lines above. */

    // You can ignore this.  It's to keep eclipse from reporting a warning
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** This is where to find the local tiles, for working without a       `                            nternet connection */
    public static String mbTilesString = "blankLight-1-3.mbtiles";

    // IF YOU ARE WORKING OFFLINE: Change the value of this variable to true
    private static final boolean offline = false;

    /** The map we use to display our home town: La Jolla, CA */
    UnfoldingMap map1;

    /** The map you will use to display your home town */ 
    UnfoldingMap map2;

    public void setup() {
        size(800, 600, P2D);  // Set up the Applet window to be 800x600
                              // The OPENGL argument indicates to use the 
                              // Processing library's 2D drawing
                              // You'll learn more about processing in  Module 3

        // This sets the background color for the Applet.  
        // Play around with these numbers and see what happens!
        this.background(200, 200, 200);

        // Select a map provider
        AbstractMapProvider provider = new Google.GoogleTerrainProvider();
        // Set a zoom level
        int zoomLevel = 10;

        if (offline) {
            // If you are working offline, you need to use this provider 
            // to work with the maps that are local on your computer.  
            provider = new MBTilesMapProvider(mbTilesString);
            // 3 is the maximum zoom level for working offline
            zoomLevel = 3;
        }


    // Create a new UnfoldingMap to be displayed in this window.  
        // The 2nd-5th arguments give the map's x, y, width and height
        // When you create your map we want you to play around with these 
        // arguments to get your second map in the right place.
        // The 6th argument specifies the map provider.  
        // There are several providers built-in.
        // Note if you are working offline you must use the MBTilesMapProvider
        map1 = new UnfoldingMap(this, 50, 50, 350, 500, provider);

        // The next line zooms in and centers the map at 
        // 32.9 (latitude) and -117.2 (longitude)
        map1.zoomAndPanTo(zoomLevel, new Location(32.9f, -117.2f));

        // This line makes the map interactive
        MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map1);

        // TODO: Add code here that creates map2 
        // Then you'll modify draw() below

    }

    /** Draw the Applet window.  */
    public void draw() {
        // So far we only draw map1...
        // TODO: Add code so that both maps are displayed
        map1.draw();
    }


    }
```

Your feedback will really be appreciated.

Comment: does it say which lib?